# How to import a table of projects into Sharepoint Lists Options and keep unpdating said projet names

Tags: sharepoint, metadata, sharepoint-online

So I have the following issue:
I don´t have the necessary privilages in my firm to manage the metadata sets but I still have to create a change log for ongoing projects. The firm has been working without said lists for years and I don´t particulary feel like typing in every single one by hand.
So my question is: is there any way for me to import a CSV or Excel table as options to choose from?

The change log list should look as follows:

| Project name | ID | Project number | Date | Title | Changes | Place of project |

I want to have the following:

- have a continuusly updating list of project names and IDs to choose from (this would be said excel table that is updated weekly) that users of the change log can chhose from but not add any other options into
- have a set list of options for titles (e.g. "status update", "building project" etc) that can be edited by a few people
- have the place of project auto filled when entering the name (same excel table also has the place)

I have not found even a hint of an idea anywherte so I would really appreciate the help

Comment: you can create a PowerApp either as a SharePoint list form or a stand-alone app. You can bring in the Excel file as a data source and use the data in the Excel file in your form dropdown controls.

Comment: but that would mean that i have to mannualy update all those options right?